# MVC Kendo two thead

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Within MVC Kendo can I have two thead rows? The first will span three tds in the second row. Below is a sample of what I am looking to do? the model is returning a list of theadViewModel.
Looking something like this using the model data?

```
               Name     
Columns1    Columns2    Columns3
ColumnsData ColumnsData ColumnsData
```

Model

```
public class theadViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<DataViewModel> DataViewModel { get; set; }
    }

 public class DataViewModel
{
    public string Columns1 { get; set; }
    public string Columns2 { get; set; }
    public string Columns3 { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
         .Name("Grid")

         .Columns(columns =>
          {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
         })
         .Pageable()
         .Sortable()
         .Scrollable()
         .Filterable()
         .Groupable()
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo Grid allows multi-column headers. You can find the documentation [here](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/multicolumnheaders).

Here is an example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CustomerViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Group(group => group
            .Title("Contact Info")
            .Columns(info => { 
                info.Bound(x => x.ContactTitle).Width(200);
                info.Bound(x => x.ContactName).Width(200);
            })
        );
    })
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorderable => reorderable.Columns(true))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 550px;" })
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("MultiColumn_Customers_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

Comment: Can the .Title be pulled from the model? its a list object from the theadViewModel?

Comment: can I do something like this .Title(Model.Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault())?